# Rooms and Guests (object add to another object?)

Tags: c#, object

Basically I am creating a hotel check in kind of system and I am wanting to create Rooms 1-100 then when I create a new object for Guest I want to assign that guest to a certain room object if you get me. Here is what I have so far for the Guest and Room Class.

EDIT: Sorry for not making clear what I was asking. I am wanting to know how I can connect a guest object to a room object using the `leadName` property if that is possible? And Also what would be the best way to store all these rooms and all their properties such as the Guests staying in them etc?

RoomClass:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hotel_Check_In
{
 public class Room
    {
     public int RoomNumber;
     public string RoomType;
     public string SmokingAllowed;
     public Boolean booked;
     private Guest LeadName;

     public Room()
     { }
    }
}
```

Guest Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hotel_Check_In
{
    public class Guest
    {
       public string LeadName;
       public int roomNumber;

       public Guest(string name, int roomN)
       {
          LeadName = name;
          roomNumber = roomN;
       }
    }    
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information on what it is that you are stuck with or want help with. Please describe what the expected behavior of your code is versus what you observed and why/where you are having trouble in finding the cause yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed it completely and used the room number to connect the room and guest using Hashtables.

```
public static Hashtable checkBookedRooms(string Rtype)
     {
         Hashtable roomsAvailable = new Hashtable();
         int i = 0;

        foreach(Room room in AllRooms)
        {
            i++;
            if(room.booked==false && room.RoomType == Rtype)
            {
                roomsAvailable.Add(room.RoomNumber, room.RoomType);
            }  
            if(i >= AllRooms.Count)
            {
                i = 0;
                return roomsAvailable;

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Room.checkBookedRooms() Returned Null");
        return null;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting lead.  I made Guest public instead of private.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Hotel_Check_In
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string lead = "JohnSmith";
            Room room = Room.rooms.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.LeadName.LeadName == lead).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public class Room
    {
        public static List<Room> rooms = null;
        public int RoomNumber;
        public string RoomType;
        public string SmokingAllowed;
        public Boolean booked;
        public Guest LeadName;

        public Room(int numberOfRooms)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRooms; i++)
            {
                Room newRoom = new Room();
                rooms.Add(newRoom);
                newRoom.RoomNumber = i;
            }
        }

    }
    public class Guest
    {
        public string LeadName;
        public int roomNumber;

        public Guest(string name, int roomN)
        {
            LeadName = name;
            roomNumber = roomN;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps

```
namespace Hotel_Check_In
{
    public class Room
    {
     public static List<Room> rooms = null;
     public int RoomNumber;
     public string RoomType;
     public string SmokingAllowed;
     public Boolean booked;
     private Guest LeadName;

     public Room(int numberOfRooms)
     {
         for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfRooms ; i++)
         {
             Room newRoom = new Room();
             rooms.Add(newRoom);
             newRoom.RoomNumber = i;
         }
     }

    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, the code snippet feature is meant for executable code snippets in JavaScript, HTML, etc.

Comment: Have you considered use SQL Server database for storage?  You can download for free the Express version from msdn.com.